# Duplicate rows in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which will remove duplicate rows with repeated `assignment_name, effective_start_date, effective_end_date, effective_latest_change`. The details of employees are there in two tables

**xx_as_table**:

```
Ass_nmber    eff_s_date             eff_e_date effective_l_change     special_ceiling         date_Start       employer_name         worker_type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10228        01-jan-1990           31-dec-4172             1                        0             01-feb-1989           XYZ Ltd           E
10228        03-feb-1989           31-dec-1989             2                        0             01-feb-1989           XYZ Ltd           E
```

**xx_wrk_table**

```
ass_number    date_Start       employer_name     worker_type
------------------------------------------------------------
10228         01-feb-1989      XYZ Ltd              E
10228         01-jan-1991      ABC Ltd              P
```

Now, I want a query which retrieves the above data as follows :

```
Ass_nmber    eff_s_date          eff_e_date           eff_l_change     special_ceiling  date_Start       employer_name         worker_type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
10228        01-jan-1990           31-dec-4172             1                        0             01-feb-1989           XYZ Ltd           E
10228        03-feb-1989           31-dec-1989             2                        0             01-feb-1989           XYZ Ltd           E
```

I want date_start from xx_wrk_table with min date_start and details against that min date_Start. And no duplicate rows should be there with same assignment_name, effective_start_date,effective_end_date,effective_latest_change

For this I have written a query :

```
select 
    ass_number,
    regexp_substr(ass_number, '[0-9]+') person_number,
    effective_start_date,
    effective_end_date,
    nvl((select min (wrk.date_start)
from   
    XX_WRK_STG
where
    WRK.PERSON_NUMBER = regexp_substr(assignment_number, '[0-9]+')), effective_start_date) D, t.effective_start_date),
        nvl(wrk.worker_type, 'E'),
        nvl(wrk.employer_name, 'XYZ'),
        effective_latest_change

      from  (SELECT xx_as_table.*,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY assignment_name, 
                                          effective_start_date,
                                          effective_end_date,
                                          effective_latest_change) AS c
        FROM   xx_as_table) T
 left outer join 
    XX_WRK_STG  wrk
on regexp_substr(t.assignment_name, '[0-9]+')=wrk.person_number
where c=1;
```

But this query is not working and against each ass_number multiple data is getting retrieved from wrk_table. How do I modify my query so that I get the expected result?

Comment: Your desired results look exactly like the first table.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 
I am trying to fetch the detail from xx_ass_table such that repeated data in assignment_name, effective_start_date,effective_end_date,effective_latest_change is removed and for date_start,worker_type and employer_name the min
date_start from xx_wrk_table should be fetched against the ass_number which is common between both tables

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your table structure completely as in your examples and written query, you have used different column names and some additional column.
Still I have tried to help. To find the row from work table having minimum date, you can use `Rank function`.

```
SELECT x_tab.Ass_nmber,  
       x_tab.eff_s_date,  
       x_tab.eff_e_date,  
       x_tab.effective_l_change,  
       x_tab.special_ceiling,  
       work_tab.date_Start,  
       work_tab.employer_name,  
       work_tab.worker_type  
  FROM (SELECT Ass_nmber,  
               eff_s_date,  
               eff_e_date,  
               effective_l_change,  
               special_ceiling,  
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Ass_nmber,  
                                           eff_s_date,  
                                           eff_e_date,  
                                           effective_l_change) cnt  
           FROM xx_as_table)x_tab,  
        (SELECT ass_number,  
                date_Start,  
                employer_name,  
                worker_type,  
                person_number,  
                RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ass_number  
                                ORDER BY date_Start DESC) rnk  
           FROM xx_wrk_table) work_tab  
   WHERE s_tab.cnt = 1  
     AND work_tab.rnk = 1  
     AND regexp_substr(s_tab.Ass_nmber, '[0-9]+') = work_tab.person_number;
```

If it doesn't help, Please provide you proper create and insert statements. That will help others to help you. Thanks.